# is it possible to obtain 'groupby-transform-apply' style results with the function return series rather than scaler?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to achieve the following behavior:

```py
res = df.groupby(['dimension'], as_index=False)['metric'].transform(lambda x: foo(x))
```

where foo(x) returns a series the same size as the input which is df['metric']
however, this will throw the following error:
ValueError: transform must return a scalar value for each group

i know i can use a for loop style, but how can i achieve this in a groupby manner?

e.g.

```
df:
   col1 col2 col3
0   A1  B1  1
1   A1  B1  2
2   A2  B2  3
```

and i want to achieve:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   A1  B1  1 - (1+2)/2
1   A1  B1  2 - (1+2)/2
2   A2  B2  3 - 3
```

Comment: can you create an example (a small dataframe)for testing? thanks

Comment: @anky_91 thanks, just added an example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a Series you should use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) instead of `transform`:

```
res = df.groupby(['dimension'], as_index=False)['metric'].apply(lambda x: foo(x))
```

[Transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform) as the error states must return a scalar value that would be put in every rows for each group. But `apply` will work with a Series returned for each group.

If this doesn't work, provide input and expected output to understand better your problem.

Comment: thanks, but this method doesn't return the column 'dimension', do you know why?

Comment: i 've just added an example, hope it help to understand the problem.

Comment: @DingxinXu - It doesn't return the column because you grouped by `'dimension'`, when way would be to store the apply in `df['res']` instead of `res`. I think you should see anky's answer because you seem to not need a function `foo` to perform your computation so you can use `transform` instead of `apply` which should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `transform`:

```
df['col3']=(df.col3-df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('sum'))/2
```

Or using `apply`(slower):

```
df['col3']=df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.sum())/2)
```

---

```
  col1 col2  col3
0   A1   B1  -1.0
1   A1   B1  -0.5
2   A2   B2   0.0
```